# Grouping items with more that one indexes into sub arrays

Tags: javascript

Trying to create a function that groups repeated items in an array into sub arrays, and also grouping strings (should there be any) into another subarray.

I tried using the findIndex method to define i and then iterate it and push in into an [], using reduce

```
let roughArray = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20];

function sortArray() {
    roughArray.map(num => {
        if (num[i] > 1) {
            roughArray.reduce((acc, num) => {
                return acc.concat(num)
            }, [])
        }
    })

sortArray()
```

I also tried:

```
const cleanArray = roughArray.reduce((acc, num) => {
    let i = acc.findIndex(num);
    if (i) {
        return acc.concat(num);
    }
}, [])
cleanArray();
```

I expect this in case of only numbers

```
 [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2], 4,5,10,[20,20], 391, 392,591]
```

And this in case of  some included strings:

```
 [[1,2], ["2", "3"]]
```

Comment: how do you decide which grouping rule you are taking?

Comment: Output for strings version needs clarification on rules. A full example would help

Comment: Ohh the Strings part wasn't so important. but what i meant was `[1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, '45'  20, ' 80']` should output as: [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2], 4,5,10,[20,20], 391, 392,591, ['45', '80' ]]

Answer (score 0):

You could declare some callbacks for the various types of grouping and get the wanted type by checking the array and take an object for the grouped values.

```js
function sortOf(array) {
    const
        mixed = (r, v) => {
            var key = typeof v;
            r[key] = r[key] || [];
            r[key].push(v);
            return r;
        },
        numbers = (r, v) => {
            if (v in r) r[v] = [].concat(r[v], v);
            else r[v] = v;
            return r;
        };

    return Object.values(array.reduce(array.some(v => typeof v === 'string')
            ? mixed
            : numbers,
        Object.create(null)
    ));
}

console.log(sortOf([1, '1', '2', 3]));
console.log(sortOf([5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Okay This worked, But I don't really get the logic.  `  return Object.values(array.reduce(array.some(v => typeof v === 'string')
            ? mixed
            : numbers,
        Object.create(null)`  
I am not sure where the object was declared

Comment: it is the accumulator of `reduce`: `Object.create(null)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here I use an object literal `{}` as the accumulator for `Array.prototype.reduce`, in case of strings in the array I used `str` as the key of the object {} accumulator and added the strings as the value. So if a string is encountered the accumulator will be `{str: "23"}`.

In case of numbers I checked if the value is repeated or not, if repeated I created an array and added the new duplicate number to it with the key being the number itself e.g. `{1: [1,1]}`

Finally when the accumulator object is constructed I just take the values part of the accumulator object using `Object.values` which I return:

```js
let roughArray = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20, "23", "23", "34"];

function group(roughArray) {
   return Object.values(roughArray.reduce((r, e) => {
     if(r['str'] && typeof e === "string"){  r['str'] = Array.isArray(r['str']) ? [...r['str']].concat(e): [r['str'], e]; }
     else if(typeof e === "string"){r['str'] = [e]}
     else if(r[e]){r[e] = Array.isArray(r[e]) ? [...r[e]].concat(e): [r[e], e];}
     else{ r[e] = e}
     return r;
   }, {}));
 }
 console.log(group(roughArray));
```

Note: `Array.isArray(r['str'])` checks whether the value of the `str` key is an array if so I can use the es6 spread operator `...` to get the old values of the array and also append the new one to the existing array.

Comment: I ran it and it worked nicely. But I find the logic quite a lot to grasp.
I would love a break down of teh logic behind the solution. Thank you

Comment: @Alara_stealth I added some more explanation, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
let roughArray = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20];
let results = {}
roughArray.map( num => {
    if(results[num])
        results[num].push(num)
    else 
        results[num] = [num]
    })
let bigArray = []
bigArray = Object.values(results)
let final_result = []
bigArray.map(array => {
    if(array.length == 1)
        final_result.push(array[0])
    else 
        final_result.push(array)
})
console.log(final_result)
```

Comment: Okay This is clean. But what if I want ` let results = [] `. 
Must I use an Object. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First separate the strings from the rest. Sort the numbers, group them, then add the strings back in at the end.

If you want to, you can then map all the single item arrays into just single items, but that seems like it would make the output confusing.

```js
let start = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20, '2', '3'];
let strings = start.filter(v => typeof(v) === 'string');
let notStrings = start.filter(v => typeof(v) !== 'string');
let sortedNotStrings = notStrings.sort((a,b) => a > b);
let grouped = sortedNotStrings.reduce((acc, value) =>
{
  if(acc.length > 0)
  {
    if(acc[0][0] === value)
    {
      acc[0].push(value);
    }
    else
    {
      acc.unshift([value]);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    acc.unshift([value]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

let sortedGrouped = grouped.sort((g1, g2) => g1[0] > g2[0]);
let withStrings = [sortedGrouped, strings];

console.log(withStrings);

let lonelySingleItems = sortedGrouped.map(arr => arr.length > 1 ? arr : arr[0]);

console.log([lonelySingleItems, strings]);
```

Regarding the if statement:

```
  if(acc.length > 0)
  {
    if(acc[0][0] === value)
    {
      acc[0].push(value);
    }
    else
    {
      acc.unshift([value]);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    acc.unshift([value]);
  }
```

What I'm doing with the reduce function is passing in a default value `[]`, so if we're at the start (i.e. the result is empty) then we put the first item in the sortedNotStrings array into the accumulating result (acc). This is what is happening in the outermost `else`.

If this isn't the beginning (i.e. acc is not empty) then we need to check if the value is the same as the last value added. If it is the same, put it into the array, otherwise start a new array in acc.

acc is an array of arrays, which is why `[value]` is being unshifted to start, rather than `value`.

In order to not have to access the last array of acc, I'm using `unshift` to put things on the front of the array. This is just to make the code look cleaner, by not using of `acc[acc.length-1]`. On the other hand you can do `acc[acc.length-1].push([value])`, and that means the `grouped.sort` is unnecessary, because the values won't be back to front.

If you have a really large array, eliminating the second sort is probably preferable to not having to type `acc.length - 1`.

Comment: Waooo This will take some understanding. I will have to seperate the two answers i.e with strings and without. Also the nested if statements is new to me, but I am brealing down the logic. 
Thank you so much.
Maybe some clarifications of the if statement logic would be nice

Comment: @Alara_stealth I've added an explanation. Let me know if there's any more detail you need.